# How to apply an expression for all children of a given element who have the same class

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a problem with sliding the menu in and out.
My categories sometimes have more than one child or grandchild and the terms I have written do not work for the deepest  with the children class.
I would like to achieve the effect that after clicking on the parent, all children get specific values ​​(closed class, style).
At this point, after pressing  for the oldest in the hierarchy, it will add only the class closed and display none to him, his children will not get these values

```js
    (function ($) {

    if ($('.cat-item ul').hasClass('children')) {
        $('ul.children').parent().addClass('sub-menu');
        $('.sub-menu').prepend('<i class="fas fa-plus open"></i>');
    }
    var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("open");
    $('.children').addClass('closed');
    $('.closed').css('display', 'none');
    Array.from(elems).forEach(v => v.addEventListener('click', function () {

        if ($(this.parentElement.getElementsByClassName('children')[0].classList.toggle('opened'))) {
            
        } else if ($(!this.parentElement.getElementsByClassName('children')[0].classList.toggle('opened'))) {
            

        }
        let c = this.parentElement.getElementsByClassName('children')[0];
        $(c).addClass('closed');
        if ($(c).hasClass('opened')) {
            $(c).removeClass('closed');
            $(c).css('display', '');

        } else {
            $(c).css('display', 'none');
            $(c).css('height', '');
        }
        (($('.children').length >= 1).find('opened').attr('closed'))
        if ($('.children .children').hasClass('opened')) {
            let h = (this.parentElement.getElementsByClassName('children opened')[0].offsetHeight);
            $(c).css('height', h);


            if (($(c).find('.children').length >= 1) && ($('.children .children').hasClass('opened'))) {
                $('.children.opened').css('height', 2 * h);
            }
            console.log(this.parentElement.getElementsByClassName('children opened')[0].offsetHeight);
        }
    }));


    })(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>    <li class="cat-item cat-item-31 sub-menu"><i class="fas fa-plus open"></i><a href="#">Aplikacje</a>
    <ul class="children opened" style="">
        <li class="cat-item cat-item-34"><a href="#">Naszywki</a>
        </li>
        <li class="cat-item cat-item-33"><a href="#">Termo</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-26 sub-menu"><i class="fas fa-plus open"></i><a href="#">Galanteria metalowa</a>
        <ul class="children closed" style="display: none;">
            <li class="cat-item cat-item-27 sub-menu"><i class="fas fa-plus open"></i><a href="#">Napy</a>
                <ul class="children closed" style="display: none;">
                    <li class="cat-item cat-item-81"><a href="#">napy test</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="cat-item cat-item-83"><a href="#">napy test 2</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="cat-item cat-item-84"><a href="#">napy test 3</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-24 sub-menu"><i class="fas fa-plus open"></i><a href="#">Galanteria plastikowa</a>
        <ul class="children closed" style="display: none;">
            <li class="cat-item cat-item-25"><a href="#">Klamry</a>
            </li>
            <li class="cat-item cat-item-35"><a href="#">Końcówki MIX</a>
            </li>
            <li class="cat-item cat-item-32"><a href="#">Przelotki</a>
            </li>
            <li class="cat-item cat-item-28"><a href="#">Ramki</a>
            </li>
            <li class="cat-item cat-item-36"><a href="#">Regulatory</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-37 sub-menu"><i class="fas fa-plus open"></i><a href="#">Koronki</a>
        <ul class="children closed" style="display: none;">
            <li class="cat-item cat-item-38"><a href="#">Bawełniane</a>
            </li>
            <li class="cat-item cat-item-39"><a href="#">Gipiura</a>
            </li>
            <li class="cat-item cat-item-40"><a href="#">Stabilna</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-41 sub-menu"><i class="fas fa-plus open"></i><a href="#">Lamówki</a>
        <ul class="children closed" style="display: none;">
            <li class="cat-item cat-item-42"><a href="#">Bawełniane</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-43 sub-menu"><i class="fas fa-plus open"></i><a href="#">Nici</a>
        <ul class="children closed" style="display: none;">
            <li class="cat-item cat-item-45"><a href="#">Hard</a>
            </li>
            <li class="cat-item cat-item-44"><a href="#">Viga</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-62"><a href="#">Przyssawki sylikonowe</a>
    </li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-46 sub-menu"><i class="fas fa-plus open"></i><a href="#">Rzep YKK</a>
        <ul class="children closed" style="display: none;">
            <li class="cat-item cat-item-47"><a href="#">Miękki</a>
            </li>
            <li class="cat-item cat-item-48"><a href="#">Ostry</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-49 sub-menu"><i class="fas fa-plus open"></i><a href="#">Taśma</a>
        <ul class="children closed" style="display: none;">
            <li class="cat-item cat-item-50"><a href="#">Nośna</a>
            </li>
            <li class="cat-item cat-item-51"><a href="#">Odblaskowe</a>
            </li>
            <li class="cat-item cat-item-52"><a href="#">Ozdobne</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-53 sub-menu"><i class="fas fa-plus open"></i><a href="#">Wypustki</a>
        <ul class="children closed" style="display: none;">
            <li class="cat-item cat-item-54"><a href="#">Bawełniane</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-55 sub-menu"><i class="fas fa-plus open"></i><a href="#">Zamki plastikowe</a>
        <ul class="children closed" style="display: none;">
            <li class="cat-item cat-item-56"><a href="#">Kryte</a>
            </li>
            <li class="cat-item cat-item-58"><a href="#">Nierozdzielcze</a>
            </li>
            <li class="cat-item cat-item-57"><a href="#">Rozdzielcze</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Show html as well.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/QKEsHyv3 HTML

Comment: i have created a snippet for you, you could added something by editing the question then *edit this snippet*..

Comment: I have created a simple example for you using jQuery. may be it will helpful. https://codepen.io/multanisadik/pen/abBxjPz

Comment: @MultaniSadik in your case, children children still does not hidden after hidden parent.

Comment: @NCTI I've updated the code for close the children items also. https://codepen.io/multanisadik/pen/abBxjPz I hope it will be helpful